# Full algorithm for rational functions integration

Tags: integration

Is there a full algorithm for finding the integral of rational functions?

Comment: [Chapter 11](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-0-585-33247-5_11) of Geddes/Czapor/Labahn has something you might be able to start with.

Answer (score 3):

According to [wikipedea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function):

> A rational function is any function which can be defined by a rational fraction.

So a rational function can be written as   a fraction of two polynomials: $$ f(x)= \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)} $$

Usually integrating such functions goes through these **General** procedures:

1. If degree of $P(x)$ is greater than or equal degree of  $Q(x)$ we use the  [Polynomial long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division): so that we may write  $$f(x)=\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}=q(x)+ \frac{r(x)}{Q(x)}  $$
   with $q(x) $  is a polynomial and  $r(x)$ is a polynomial whose degree is less than strictly the degree of  $Q(x)$. Note that integrating a polynomial is the most easy integrating part (I mean here integrating  $q(x)$), thus we are left with  the new  retional fucntion $\frac{r(x)}{Q(x)}$ where degree of the numerator is strictly less than the degree of the denominator, so move to the second case
2. If degree of  $P(x)$ is less than stricly degree of  $Q(x)$.

If degree$Q(x)- $degree$P(x)=1$, ( except the case constant over polynomail of degree one which integrate into logarithm)  try to modify the numerator ( using multiplication/division by a scalar and/or adding/subtracting   a polynomial) in order to end up with  a new numerator  $\hat{P}(x)$ such that $$ Q'(x)=\hat{P}(x) $$ Then for integrating this, you may use change of variable  with   : let $u= Q(x)$  and  $du= \hat{P}(x) dx$. A small simple example to clarify the idea here is  integrating  $f(x)=\frac{x}{x^2+1}$  or   $g(x)=\frac{2x^2}{ x^3+x^2+1}$. Note that for integrating $g(x)$ you may not only multiply  and divide the function by  $\frac{3}{2}$ but you have also to add  and   subtract after $2x$  so you get  $$\frac{2x^2}{ x^3+x^2+1}= \frac{2}{3}\frac{3x^2+2x-2x }{ x^3+x^2+1} =\frac{2}{3}\frac{3x^2+2x-2x }{ x^3+x^2+1}- \frac{2}{3}\frac{2x }{ x^3+x^2+1} $$ The first part is clearly as I explained above,  for the second part we move to the following cases.

If degree$Q(x)- $degree$P(x)>1$, then you may use the [Partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition), turning your fraction into much more simple fractions hopefully with the difference between the degree of the numerator and the denominator is one.

A special that you mmay usually recognize, is when having an constant over a degree two polynomail, in this case the $ \arctan $ function will solve the problem by complete squaring the denominator.

I don,t have a full algorithm for integrating a fractional function, but I think this may lead you to an outline:  how you can proceed in some general cases.